# Azure AD Graph API - isMemberOf and local groups

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Graph API's isMemberOf function to test whether a user is a member of a particular group. This works great for Office 365 groups, but always seems to return false for "Local Active Directory" groups. I'm assuming the local groups are being synced correctly as I can see them and their membership list using the Azure AD portal.

Is it possible to test for group membership of local active directory groups using the Graph API?

Comment: HI Paul, have you tried using the Graph API to query for the Group itself, and if the group object exists in the Graph API, then query for the users in that group? That way we could at least see if there are issues syncing the group to the directory, or even the users to the group.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I've just tried this - the group and it's users come back fine using the Graph API. The users are directly in the group, so there's no nesting getting in the way

Comment: OK, so the isMemberOf seems to be working now